# Invalid datasource when importing from Google Drive

Tags: qgis, layers, google

I am using QGIS 3.2 and attempting to import a layer definition file stored on a company Google drive. Every time I import the file I get an "invalid datasource" error and I am unable to view the attribute table and my features do not appear. Does anybody know how to solve this?

[image]